# IIS configuration issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller

I work on a basic application asp.net MVC for testing Ical. My issue is when I deploy on IIS.

On my personal computer the url: http://localhost/Ical show the form and when I post form, I call http://localhost/Ical/Home/ShowTask and browser show my task.

But if I deploy on my work computer, when I post the form, browser try to show http://localhost/Home/ShowTask and I have a 404 error. I do not understand why I lost \ical in my url

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Can you please mention what steps did you followed to deploy your site on local IIS?

Comment: I use visual studio 2017 to deploy. I right clic on my project then publish. I use system files on publish method and I give an adress folder like D:\PublishProject\Ical. Then I use this folder on IIS as phisycal path when I deploy. And I use a specific pool for this application.

Comment: @roukish On your personal computer are you deploying under ical sub-application of default website? Check how ical is configured on your personal computer

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood On the two case (persoonal computer and work computer) I publish in IIS under Default Web Site with "add an application"

Comment: This issue may occur insufficient permission to particular folder, check whether you have added ISUSER permission to  D:\PublishProject\Ical ?

Comment: @Shanjee I add permission for ISUSER but issue is still present. In add if I put manually url http://localhost/Ical/Home/ShowTask on my work computer browser, I show the task (but task is empty)

Comment: @roukish Please compare the personal vs work computer IIS Default website/ical. I am assuming that you have ical application under Default Website on both PCs. From where the task data is loaded?  Do you have any other routes on ical applications that loading fine on work computer?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes my application is under default WebSite on my two computer. The data for the task come from the Home/Index page (user enter data). My application is very basic only one controller (HomeController) and 3 action (one for show form, the second for resume task and ask mail for send .ics file and the last is to send mail with the ics file)